# Set vector element by name

Tags: r

who can help with this question

```
> ranks
 first second  third
     1      2      3
> ranks["first"]
first 
    1
```

How do I  set the value for the "third" rank to something other than 3 using the name rather than the position?

Comment: Is this really off topic? Its a bit weak, but is about R programming...

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
> ranks=1:3
> names(ranks)=c("first","second","third")
> ranks["first"]
first 
    1 
> ranks["third"]=999
> ranks
 first second  third 
     1      2    999
```